# Python appending to and yielding a list

Tags: python, generator

What is going on here? Why does `list(f(seq))` return something other than a list of the elements yielded by `f`?

```
>>> def f(seq):
...   a = []
...   for i in seq:
...     yield a
...     a.append(i)
...
>>> f([1,2,3])
<generator object f at 0x1066c7aa0>
>>> b = f([1,2,3])
>>> b.next()
[]
>>> b.next()
[1]
>>> b.next()
[1, 2]
>>> b.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> list(f([1,2,3]))
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: One solution to remove this dependency is to shallow copy the list as you yield, replacing `yield a` with `yield a[:]`. It's a lot of copying, but if you want independent lists returned, it's necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have yielded the entire reference to the list `a` inside the function.  When `list(f([1,2,3]))` is called the result simply is `[a, a, a]`, and the final form of `a` is `[1, 2, 3]`.

This is no different if you had saved all the results from the `f.next()` calls.

```
>>> v1 = b.next()
>>> v2 = b.next()
>>> v1
[1]
>>> v2
[1]
>>> v3 = b.next()
>>> v4 = b.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> v1
[1, 2, 3]
```

Again, this is correct because `a` is yielded and is the same reference to the same internal list inside the function `f`.

Comment: @achampion Had to roll back your edit, because you didn't actually run his code in your Python shell to see that output is exactly as is.

Comment: Acknowledged, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You are yielding the list you created in the generator and not a copy of the list. Lists are mutable so **any changes to that list are reflected in all references to that list**.
Consider this:

```
>>> a = [[]]*4      # Create a list of 4 references to the same list
>>> a[0].append(1)  # Add 1 the first reference
>>> a
[[1], [1], [1], [1]]
```